# How to get Admin user's email_id or id who created a specific product?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Is there a way to get the admin user details who created a particular product?

E.g. I have 10 admin users with specific roles, so that all of them can create a new product.

Now, from a product I want to get the admin user's details(one of the ten) who created the product.

Is there any product attribute or any event logging or something?

Answer (score 0):

You must have an admin_id field in product table in your database. And foreign key from this admin_id to admin table id field.

Comment: which table are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

**Magento** does not provide such functionality. You need to create your own while creating any product.

```
$admin_id=Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
```

you can create a column in product table named **admin_id** and create hidden field in the product create form.

Hope this will help you.